# MongoDB index converts to numberlong

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, schema, database

I'm trying to create a MongoDB index on a specific field with the following input:

Collection: messages

```
source_id (integer)
message_id (string)
subject (string)
timestamp (integer)
```

I'm in need to query this collection on the source and uid fields.

Example document:

```
{ 
 "_id" : ObjectId("53aad315bffebc5d378b4569"), 
 "source_id" : NumberLong(1), 
 "message_id" : "AMA9D2TP9zWA.kuhlman.lowell@dietrich.com", 
 "subject" : "Labore aut est amet temporibus mollitia et.", 
 "timestamp" : NumberLong(1364645191) 
}
```

A simple db.messages.getIndexes() returns that my message_id index is a NumberLong?

```
> db.messages.getIndexes()
[
{
    "v" : 1,
    "name" : "_id_",
    "key" : {
        "_id" : 1
    },
    "ns" : "hs.messages"
},
{
    "v" : 1,
    "name" : "s_1",
    "key" : {
        "s" : NumberLong(1)
    },
    "ns" : "hs.messages"
},
{
    "v" : 1,
    "name" : "m_1",
    "key" : {
        "m" : NumberLong(1)
    },
    "ns" : "hs.messages"
}
]
```

Comment: The number following the field specifies the sort direction. I would not expect the type to be NumberLong however. Can you share the commands used to create the indexes?

Comment: @James $collection->index('source_id'); $collection->index('message_id'); with https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb

Comment: The sort direction being written as NumberLong would be an artifact of either the laravel-mongodb code or underlying client software. It may be worth filing a Github issue to that project. The index should work fine in any case. I tested this in the mongo shell, forcing the sort direction to be NumberLong. Queries against this index work as expected. You can test yourself by running a query that should use the index and appending a .explain()